# Is any dual metrizable locally convex space a Frechet space?

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, duality-theorems, dual-spaces

The title basically says all of it.

If a normed space $F$ is a dual of a normed space $E$, then $F$ is a Banach space. I wonder if the same holds for Frechet spaces.

The strong dual $F$ of a locally convex space $E$ is complete, once $E$ is bornological, but I am not sure if this is the case here. Perhaps the completion of $E$ is though.

Comment: Now also posted on MathOverflow: [Is any dual metrizable locally convex space a Frechet space?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/280048) I think that [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088) give a very reasonable advice on cross-posting. Of course, added discussions tagged ([meta-tag:cross-posting]) might be of interest, too.